# DB2 SQL Check Constraint

Tags: sql, db2

I want to create a check constraint in DB2 that will check each char of a cell and then only allows specific values. I have tried many different way

```
 add check (substr(term, 1, 1) LIKE '[WS]' 
            and substr(term, 2, 1) = 'S' 
            and substr(term, 3, 2) LIKE '[0-9]') 
            and substr(term, 5, 2) LIKE '[ 0-9]')
```

How can I set a range in which a char has to be?

Comment: what platform and version of DB2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a regular expression syntax but you have to specify SQL.
So it should look like

```
add check ((substr(text, 1,1)='W' or substr(text, 1,1)='S') 
           and substr(text, 2,1)='S' 
           and substr(text, 3,1) between 0 and 9 )
```

Now with DB2 LUW 11.1 you could also use regular expressions - something like:

```
add check (regexp_like(text, '[WS]+'))
```

This is just an example you have to adjust the regular expression to your needs.

Comment: Note: in DB2 for i (not luw) the REGEXP_LIKE predicate is not allowed in a Check constraint condition. I would be surprised if DB2 LUW allowed them

Comment: @Unai Vivi you should be surprised though ... it works ... it is tested ... it is true